# RHEL6: Tomcat runs as unconfined Java user

Tags: redhat, selinux

I'm starting to configure RHEL6 to be a hardened Tomcat server and applying SELinux policies for access control. After installing RHEL6 and Tomcat6 (standalone, no httpd), I noticed that the Tomcat process was running as unconfined_java_t. How can I confine Tomcat to a domain of choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of RHEL6, the default SELinux user mappings are as follows

```
# semanage user -l

                Labeling   MLS/       MLS/
SELinux User    Prefix     MCS Level  MCS Range                      SELinux Roles

git_shell_u     user       s0         s0                             git_shell_r
guest_u         user       s0         s0                             guest_r
root            user       s0         s0-s0:c0.c1023                 staff_r sysadm_r system_r unconfined_r
staff_u         user       s0         s0-s0:c0.c1023                 staff_r sysadm_r system_r unconfined_r
sysadm_u        user       s0         s0-s0:c0.c1023                 sysadm_r
system_u        user       s0         s0-s0:c0.c1023                 system_r unconfined_r
unconfined_u    user       s0         s0-s0:c0.c1023                 system_r unconfined_r
user_u          user       s0         s0                             user_r
xguest_u        user       s0         s0                             xguest_r
```

If you are using a standard `targeted` policy (check `/etc/selinux/config` or run `sestatus` to find out), odds are `root` is using the `unconfined_u` SELinux user mapping. `id -Z` as `root` will tell you.

If you check `/etc/init.d/tomcat{6,7}`, you will find an `if` switch that states that `runuser` must be used instead of plain `su` in SELinux enabled systems. This command, however, doesn't prevent the SELinux user mapping from being inherited by the `tomcat` java process.

This is relevant, as I'll try to show:

Grab the [`selinux-policy`](http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/selinux-policy-3.7.19-195.el6_4.6.src.rpm) SRPM, find the `java` module source code (file contexts, interface and type enforcement):

```
selinux-policy-3.7.19-195.el6_4.6.src/serefpolicy-3.7.19/policy/modules/apps/java.fc
selinux-policy-3.7.19-195.el6_4.6.src/serefpolicy-3.7.19/policy/modules/apps/java.if
selinux-policy-3.7.19-195.el6_4.6.src/serefpolicy-3.7.19/policy/modules/apps/java.te
```

The first one is self explanatory. It contains the paths which, in this case, will be labeled `java_exec_t`: binaries and libraries both from standard and optional locations.

The second one is possibly the most difficult to understand. It defines the allowed domain transitions within this policy module. One snippet is relevant to your question:

```
 template(`java_role_template',`
   gen_require(`
     type java_exec_t;
   ')

   type $1_java_t;
   domain_type($1_java_t)
   domain_entry_file($1_java_t, java_exec_t)
   role $2 types $1_java_t;

   domain_interactive_fd($1_java_t)
   userdom_manage_tmpfs_role($2, $1_java_t)
   allow $1_java_t self:process { ptrace signal getsched execmem execstack };
   dontaudit $1_java_t $3:tcp_socket { read write };
   allow $3 $1_java_t:process { getattr ptrace noatsecure signal_perms };
   domtrans_pattern($3, java_exec_t, $1_java_t)
   corecmd_bin_domtrans($1_java_t, $3)
   dev_dontaudit_append_rand($1_java_t)
   files_execmod_all_files($1_java_t)
   fs_dontaudit_rw_tmpfs_files($1_java_t)

   optional_policy(`
     xserver_role($2, $1_java_t)
   ')
 ')
```

As the documentation on that template states, "this template creates derived domains **which are used for java applications**", where "the prefix of the user domain (e.g., user is the prefix for user_t)", the "the role associated with the user domain" and "the type of the user domain" are all taken from the SELinux user executing the Java application.

Finally, the third file contains the type enforcement rules and boolean definitions.

Now, if your intention is to run Java applications using a confined SELinux user, you need to write a custom policy, as in the current reference policy there's no such thing (not in RHEL6, nor upstream, I think). You could start by duplicating the files and experiment from there.

Surely it is not an easy task.